# php writing one character to database from an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array

```
// Send to recipients...
$goodFriends = array_unique($goodFriends);
$MAIL->sendMail('', // Not used..
                  $goodFriends,
                  $_POST['name'],
                  $_POST['email'],
                  str_replace(array('{website}','{sender}'),array(WEBSITE_NAME,$_POST['name']),$msg_subject3),
                  $MAIL->template(FOLDER_PATH.'templates/email/friend.html')
                );

if(is_array($goodFriends)){                      
  foreach($goodFriends as $value){
    $user_id = (int) $value['user_id'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['name'] );
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['email'] );
    $referrer = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO referred (id, emailid, name, date, referredby) values ('$user_id', '$email', '$name', '$date', '$referrer')";
    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
  }

  $len = strlen($query) - 1;
  $query = substr($query,0,$len); //removing last ,
  $sql_query = mysql_query($query);

}
```

It writes the referer as a email into database, but now only stores the first character of the referred peoples names and emails

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: debug:`echo $sql; print_r($goodFriends);`

Comment: INSERT INTO referred (id, emailid, name, date, referredby) values ('0', 'k', 'k', '2015-10-22 20:48:08', 'email@gmail.com')Array ( [0] => kevin##email@email.ac.za [1] => kevin 2##email@email.ac.za [2] => kevin 3##email@email.co.za ) I see that it is writing the three arrays, do I need to alter the php in some way to write the other information?

Answer (score 0):

Not To worry... finally figured it out thank you for all the help.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO referred (id,  name, emailid, date, referredby, friend1, friend2, friend3) values ('$user_id', '$name','$email',  '$date', '$referrer', '$goodFriends[0].$email[0]', '$goodFriends[1].$email[1]', '$goodFriends[2].$email[3]')";

Answer (score -1):

Can you check your Table structure, may you forgot to add sufficient space to **emailid** and **name** fields??

Comment: they both set to varchar (100)